# Ciclo while de Javascript no finaliza en el primer intento sino en el segundo

Tags: javascript, bucles, while, switch

En este código no logro hacer que el ciclo while finalice una vez se cumpla la condición, es decir, se introduzcan las letras "esc". He intentado colocando en diversos lugares del código la instrucciones del prompt, sobre todo dentro y fuera del while, tanto al principio como al final, pero igual no pude encontrar el error de por qué no sale a la primera sino después de otro intento. Hasta llegué a pensar que tenía que ver el condicional del switch pero creo que no.

```
    alert(
  "Los productos disponibles son los siguientes: Queso, Fideos, Berenjena"
);

function ProductoCantidad() {
  let producto = "";
  let precioFinal = 0;
  let cantidad = 0;

  while (producto != "esc") {
    let aux = 0;

    producto = prompt(
      "Ingrese el producto que desea (Escriba esc para finalizar)"
    );
    cantidad = parseInt(
      prompt("Ingrese la cantidad que quiere llevar del mismo")
    );

    switch (producto.toLowerCase().trim()) {

      case "queso":
        aux = cantidad * 160;
        precioFinal += aux;
        break;

      case "fideos":
        aux = cantidad * 70;
        precioFinal += aux;
        break;

      case "berenjena":
        aux = cantidad * 90;
        precioFinal += aux;
        break;

      default:
        return precioFinal;
    }
  }
}
let valorFinal = ProductoCantidad();
alert("El valor a pagar es de $" + valorFinal);
```

Comment: no entiendo. Tu condición para mantenerte en el bucle es que producto != "salir", pero en tu descripción dices que no sale con las letras "esc". No sera que esta condición de mantenerse en el bucle es errónea?

Comment: Perdón, @Jakala ya lo actualicé. En realidad debería salir con "esc"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

¿Y si le pones un condicional justo después del prompt para detectar si es "esc"?

De este modo:

```
if(producto.toLowerCase().trim() == "esc") {
      return precioFinal;
}
```

Ejemplo:

```js
alert(
  "Los productos disponibles son los siguientes: Queso, Fideos, Berenjena"
);

function ProductoCantidad() {
  let producto = "";
  let precioFinal = 0;
  let cantidad = 0;

  while (producto != "esc") {
    let aux = 0;

    producto = prompt(
      "Ingrese el producto que desea (Escriba salir para finalizar)"
    );
    
    if(producto.toLowerCase().trim() == "esc") {
      return precioFinal;
    }
    
    cantidad = parseInt(
      prompt("Ingrese la cantidad que quiere llevar del mismo")
    );

    switch (producto.toLowerCase().trim()) {

      case "queso":
        aux = cantidad * 160;
        precioFinal += aux;
        break;

      case "fideos":
        aux = cantidad * 70;
        precioFinal += aux;
        break;

      case "berenjena":
        aux = cantidad * 90;
        precioFinal += aux;
        break;

      default:
        alert(
          "¡Producto no disponible! Los productos disponibles son los siguientes: Queso, Fideos, Berenjena"
        );
        break;
    }
  }
}
let valorFinal = ProductoCantidad();
alert("El valor a pagar es de $" + valorFinal);
```

Comment: acabo de actualizar el código @masterguru pues no era "salir" sino "esc", pero imagino que lo que me propones serviría igual

Comment: La condición del `while` y el caso `default` son innecesarios. En mi respuesta lo simplifiqué.

Comment: @OtroMasComoTu Si, deberia ser lo mismo. He actualizado mi respuesta y en el default le he puesto un alert para recordarle al usuario los productos disponibles, pues se ha equivocado.

Answer (score 1):

```js
function ProductoCantidad() {
  let producto = "";
  let precioFinal = 0;
  let cantidad = 0;

  while (true) {
    let aux = 0;

    producto = prompt(
      "Ingrese el producto que desea (Escriba esc para finalizar)"
    );

    if (producto === 'esc') return precioFinal;

    cantidad = parseInt(
      prompt("Ingrese la cantidad que quiere llevar del mismo")
    );

    switch (producto.toLowerCase().trim()) {
      case "queso":
        aux = cantidad * 160;
        precioFinal += aux;
        break;

      case "fideos":
        aux = cantidad * 70;
        precioFinal += aux;
        break;

      case "berenjena":
        aux = cantidad * 90;
        precioFinal += aux;
        break;
    }
  }
}

let valorFinal = ProductoCantidad();
alert("El valor a pagar es de $" + valorFinal);
```